# SDL_FiillRect(): Unsupported surface format or Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have a little SDL2 program that create a white window. It works perfectly. But when I try to create a `SDL_Renderer` with the function `SDL_CreateRenderer()`, the function `SDL_FillRect()` suddenly fail with the following error: **SDL_FillRect(): Unsupported surface format**. Sometimes, the function doesn't return an error but produce a Segmentation fault!!

Here is the code of my initialize function, which is the first function of my program:

```
SDL_Surface     *screenSurface  = NULL;
SDL_Window      *window         = NULL;
SDL_Renderer    *renderer       = NULL; 

bool initialize() {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) < 0) {
    cout << "SDL could not initialize: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return false;                                                               
  }                                                                             
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS);
  if (window == NULL) {                                                         
    cout << "Window error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
   return false;                                                               
  }
  if ((screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)) == NULL) {
    cout << "GetWindowSurface() error: << endl;
    return false;
  }

  /*
  ** here, I create my SDL_Renderer. The function returns non NULL
  ** However, if the code is present, SDL_FilRect() fails
  ** if the code is not preset, SDL_FillRect works.
  */ 
  if ((renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED)) == NULL) {
    cout << "Renderer error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return false;                                                               
  }

  /*
  ** Here, SDL_FillRect sometimes works depending on SDL_CreateRenderer
  ** getUint32Color() is only a custom function that map an enum with Uint32 values
  */
  if (SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, getUint32Color(WHITE)) < 0) {           
    cout << "SDL_FillRect error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
   return false;
  }
  return true;                                                                  
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure getUint32Color returns a valid color?
Why do you use FillRect if you're using an SDL_Renderer?
How do you show the surface on the screen?

Comment: Yes i'm sure for getUint32Color(), when I display the values they are valid, and the problem is not related to it. 
I use FillRect() to draw the white background and I would like to use SDL_Renderer() to draw a line (I'm new with SDL, It might not be the good way to do that). 
And to finish, I show the surface on the screen with SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window), but it doesn't matter because my code doesn't reach this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using SDL_GetWindowSurface() as the surface may become invalid.

Instead, if you absolutely want 'software' rendering which is slow:

```
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, W, H, 32, 0x00FF, 0x0000FF, 0x000000FF, 0xFF);

SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(rendered, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, W, H);

void update_screen() {
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, surface->pixels, surface->pitch);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dest); // src texture, dest
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

But as said by @Ivan, using 2D Accelerated Rendering functions is much faster.
Instead of SDL_FillRect() you should use [SDL_RenderFillRect()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect).

Comment: @Jérémy, if you want a small but complete example of SDL2 code with SDL_RenderFillRect(), see my [drawpoint](https://bitbucket.org/josephpaul0/drawpoints/src/6a5e17a965ec58edc4d3479806f06a7f244c7a8d/src/drawpoints.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) demo.

Comment: Thank you for your demo, it helps me to have a better understanding of SDL. And thanks to your answer I now only use renderer. But I don't know if I can accept your answer because it's not really a solution to my question nor an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the windows' surface and try to use a renderer on the same window. This is not allowed. From the documentation of SDL_GetWindowSurface:

> You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.

I guess, that creating the renderer immediately invalidates something in the surface.